# Why Laravel Auth::attempt method is not working?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to do user authentication, method Auth::attempt() is not working, but data is correct (laravel 5.2)

```
public function postLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'password' => 'required'
    ]);

    $username = $request->input('name');
    $password = $request->input('password');


    if (Auth::attempt(['name' => $username, 'password' => $password])) {
        return redirect('home.get');
    } else {
        return "FALSE";
    }
```

Comment: instead of return redirect() use this 


return redirect()->intended(route('home.get'));

Comment: but if block is not working

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: the data is correct but if block is not working and working else

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the php artisan make:auth. There's a "use AuthenticatesUsers;" the default code will login and check with email and password. Hence, you need to copy the credential function put into LoginController (override the default code). The code below shows how to login using Email or name with password.

```
protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    $field = filter_var($request->get($this->name()), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)
        ? $this->name()
        : 'name';

    return [
        $field => $request->get($this->name()),
        'password' => $request->password,
    ];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to attempt by email and password by default

Comment: can i use 'username' but not email?

Comment: you did not mention that you've reconfigured default email to 'name'
Even if you have username it should be 'username' not 'name'
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication#authenticating-users

Comment: i asked it for example